# Problems with adding button to div elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript and to get the hang of it i am trying to make a 2 do list where the end goal is to create a drag and drop list with my to2dos.

My problem is that when i click the + button that adds divs to the page it only creates delete buttons in the first div.

I searched for some hours on this forum and google could not find an answer and have been struggled for hours ... :-)

I hope you guys can give me a hint. Thanks!

HTML code:

```
<body>
<header class="header">
    <h1>The Drag&Drop2Do</h1>
</header>

<section class="worksection">
    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Dagens opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Færdige opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Udskudte opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Afsluttet opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>

<div class="buttonwrapper">
    <button id="btn">+</button>
</div>

<script src="./javascript/script.js"></script>
```

CSS code (not all ofcourse :-) ):

```
.workrowtask {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.worktaskdelbtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const workRow = document.querySelector('.workrow');

btn.addEventListener('click', makePost);

function makePost() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
  div.appendChild(textnode);
  div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  div.className += ('workrowtask');
  workRow.appendChild(div);


  const workrowtask = document.querySelector('.workrowtask');
  const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
  const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
  delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
  delbtn.className += ('worktaskdelbtn');
  workrowtask.appendChild(delbtn);
};
```

Here is a JSBin to show the delete buttons https://jsbin.com/xezoxitari/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: By the way, `Drag&Drop2Do` is invalid HTML. You need to write `Drag&amp;Drop2Do`.

Comment: @Christian Robbers Rasmussen. I added a solution for you. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @HenryDev Thank you for the good answer! It worked well and i learned something new :-)

Comment: @ChristianRobbersRasmussen I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append your button to the div before appending it to workRow. Here's a working solution:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const workRow = document.querySelector('.workrow');

btn.addEventListener('click', makePost);

function makePost() {   

    const workrowtask = document.querySelector('.workrowtask');
    const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
    const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
    delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
    delbtn.className += ('worktaskdelbtn');

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
    div.appendChild(textnode);
    div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    div.className += ('workrowtask');
    div.appendChild(delbtn);
    workRow.appendChild(div);

};
```

```css
.workrowtask {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.worktaskdelbtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="worksection">
    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Dagens opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Færdige opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Udskudte opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Afsluttet opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>

<div class="buttonwrapper">
    <button id="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line
workRow.appendChild(div).
is only appending the div to the first workRow, you would need to create a new workRow and append it to that.

Comment: Its also the purpose of it. In the end you will be able to drag the divs to the other workRows :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace your function with below JS function, you will see the result.**

```
function makePost() {
 const div = document.createElement('div');
 const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
 div.appendChild(textnode);
 div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
 div.className += ('workrowtask');

 const workrowtask = document.querySelector('.workrowtask');
 const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
 const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
 delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
 delbtn.className += ('worktaskdelbtn');
 div.appendChild(delbtn);
 workRow.appendChild(div);
};
```